# How to resolve a promise with a parameter in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

I am trying to resolve a promise after a particular time. This works whenever the resolve function does not have a parameter, but If I want to pass a message and handle it in .then() , the setTimeout part does not work.

For ex in the below code the setTimeout works and promise gets resolved after a particular time:

```js
function wait_time(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //console.log(time)
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
    console.log("Waiting")
    console.log("Still Waiting")
    console.log("Still Waiting")
  })
}

wait_time(800).then((response) => {
  console.log('Hello!' + response)
});
```

The output of this is as seen below

> Waiting
>
> Still Waiting
>
> Still Waiting
>
> Hello!undefined

Now I modified the code as below to pass a parameter via resolve to be handled in .then()

```js
function wait_time(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve('Time'), reject) => {
    //console.log(time)
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
    console.log("Waiting")
    console.log("Still Waiting")
    console.log("Still Waiting")
  })
}

wait_time(800).then((response) => {
  console.log('Hello!' + response)
});
```

The Output I expect here is

> Waiting
>
> Still Waiting
>
> Still Waiting
>
> Hello!Time

But the Output I get is

> Hello!Time

It seems the delay does not come into play and promise immediately gets resolved.

Would be great if someone could point out the exact issue and the concept around this?

Comment: The output I get from your second snippet is a syntax error.

Comment: Use `setTimeout(resolve.bind(this, 'Time'), time)` to bind parameter

Comment: @Kenny `setTimeout(resolve, time, 'Time')`…